# Can't identify syntax error? Also, need using raw_input with list

Tags: python, list, variables, syntax, raw-input

I'm trying to develop a simple Python program to calculate the formula mass of a compound. I'm facing 2 issues:

There's apparently a syntax error with 'b' but I don't know what it is. Here is what I've done so far:

```
def FormulaMass():
    H = 1
    He = 4
    Li = 7
    Be = 9
    B = 11
    C = 12
    N = 14
    O = 16
    F = 19
    Ne = 20
    Na = 23
    Mg = 24
    Al = 27
    Si = 28
    P = 31
    S = 32
    Cl = 35.5
    Ar = 40
    K = 39
    Ca = 40
    Sc = 45
    Ti = 48
    V = 51
    Cr = 52
    Mn = 55
    Fe = 56
    Co = 59
    Ni = 59
    Cu = 63.5
    Zn = 65
    Ga = 70
    Ge = 73
    As = 75
    Se = 79
    Br = 80
    Rb = 85.5
    Sr = 88
    Y = 89
    Zr = 91
    Nb = 93
    Mo = 96
    Tc = 98
    Ru = 101
    Rh = 103
    Pd = 106.5
    Ag = 108
    Cd = 112.5
    In = 115
    Sn = 119
    Sb = 122
    Te = 128
    I =127
    Xe = 131
    Cs = 133
    Ba = 137
    La = 139
    Ce = 140
    Pr = 141
    Nd = 144
    Pm = 145
    Sm = 150
    Eu = 152
    Gd = 157
    Tb = 159
    Dy = 162.5
    Ho = 165
    Er = 167
    Tm = 169
    Yb = 173
    Lu = 175
    Hf = 178.5
    Ta = 181
    W = 184
    Re = 186
    Os = 190
    Ir = 192
    Pt = 195
    Au = 197
    Hg = 201
    Tl = 204
    Pb = 207
    Bi = 209
    Po = 209
    At = 210
    Rn = 222
    Fr = 223
    Ra = 226
    Ac = 227
    Th = 232
    Pa = 231
    U = 238
    Np = 237
    Pu = 244
    Am = 243
    Cm = 247
    Bk = 247
    Cf = 251
    Es = 252
    Fm = 257
    Md = 258
    No = 259
    Rf = 261
    Db = 262
    Sg = 266
    Bh = 264
    Hs = 277
    Mt = 268
    Ds = 271
    Rg = 272
    Uub = 285
    Uut = 284
    Uuq = 289
    Uup = 288
    Uuh = 292
    Uuo = 294

    element = [H, He, Li, Be, B. C, N, O, F, Ne, Na, Mg, Al, Si, P, S, Cl, Ar, K, Ca, Sc, Ti, V, Cr, Mn, Fe, Co, Ni, Cu, Zn, Ga, Ge, As, Se, Br, Rb, Sr, Y, Zr, Nb, Mo, Tc, Ru, Rh, Pd, Ag, Cd, In, Sn, Sb, Te, I, Xe, Cs, Ba, La, Ce, Pr, Nd, Pm, Sm, Eu, Gd, Tb, Dy, Ho, Er, Tm, Yb, Lu, Hf, Ta, W, Re, Os, Ir, Pt, Au, Hg, Tl, Pb, Bi, Po, At, Rn, Fr, Ra, Ac, Th, Pa, U, Np, Pu, Am, Cm, Bk, Cf, Es, Fm, Md, No, Rf, Db, Sg, Bh, Hs, Mt, Ds, Rg, Uub, Uut, Uuq, Uup, Uuh, Uuo]

    a = raw_input('Which' + str(element) + '?')
    b = float(raw_input('How many moles?'))
    c = str(raw_input('Is that all [Y/N]?'))


    while c == 'N':
        print
```

1. 'a' doesn't actually come up when running the code it just immediately identifies this syntax error in 'b'.

What I'm trying to do with 'a' is to allow the user to input a constant from the list 'element' so that the mass (depending on the number of moles can be calculated). Now one potential problem I see is that I'm not sure how to allow users to input different elements with different numbers of moles without creating endless constants (e.g. a, b ,c...).

The aim is to add a*b at the end to find the mass but is there a way to make multiple a's and b's so in theory users could have a*b + a1*b1...

PS Sorry for not putting in my code properly it would take too long for me to put 4 indents after each line :/

Comment: To get the formatting right, simply paste the raw code into the edit box, select it, and then click the button which looks like two braces `{}` (or hit control-K).  That will tell SO that you want the selected region of text treated as a code sample.

Comment: What does the actual error message say?

Comment: your `print` is incomplete and You can write: `raw_input('Which' + str(element) + '?')`  as `raw_input('Which' + ', '.join(element) + '?')`

Answer (score 3):

In the `element` list, you've done `Be, B. C, N`. Notice how you used a period after the 'B' rather then using a comma.

What Python is thinking that you're doing is doing `B.C` -- you have some sort of object named `B`, and are trying to get the attribute `C` on it. Hence the error message -- `B`, an integer, has no attribute named `C`.

---

There are also a few potential issues with your code. As one commentator noted, your `print` statement is incomplete.

I'm also assuming that you want the user to enter a given element (such as `'Ne'`), then find the mass of that atom (`20`), then do some manipulation there.

In that case, you probably want to restructure your code so that it uses a dict and looks something like this:

```
def FormulaMass():
    elements = {
        'H': 1,
        'He':4, 
         # ... etc
        'Uuo': 294
    }

    element = raw_input('Which element? ')
    mass = elements[element]

    print mass
    # add math here

# Run function:
FormulaMass()
```

Comment: Even though this was a little slow :^), I'm going to delete mine in favour of it because you beat me to the suggestion to use a real data structure.  I'd probably even put the element table in a flat user-readable format and then construct a dict from that.

Comment: @Michael0x2a Thank you, I've never known about the dict function before so that was useful. However, when I run the code that you just posted nothing happens and I'm not sure why :/

Comment: @JonathanLahdo -- Did you make sure to call the function somewhere? (You have the line `FormulaMass()` somewhere in your code). Also, the code I posted contains no `print` statements, so it won't really do anything besides prompting for which element you want. (I tweaked my answer a bit to make it clearer what I mean)

Comment: @Michael0x2a No I  didn't, stupid mistake on my behalf :3 Thanks for editing your answer to make it clearer.